# Okta for Superset not working as expected

Tags: okta, apache-superset

I am attempting to integrate Okta into Apache Superset, but it's not working as expected.

When I attempt to login using Okta, I see a login screen which tells me, that `The request to sign in was denied.`

The Logs for Superset do not display any errors or logs regarding the attempted authorization.

The relevant parts of my `superset_config.py` are:

```
# Okta Login Logic:
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION = True
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE = "Public"

OKTA_BASE_URL = "my_url.okta.com"
AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_OAUTH

OKTA_CLIENT_ID = os.environ.get("OKTA_CLIENT_ID")
OKTA_CLIENT_SECRET = os.environ.get("OKTA_CLIENT_SECRET")


class CustomSsoSecurityManager(SupersetSecurityManager):
    def oauth_user_info(self, provider, response=None):

        if provider == "my_company_name": #perhaps this should be okta?
            user_info = self.appbuilder.sm.oauth_remotes[provider].parse_id_token(
                response
            )

            return {
                "name": user_info["name"],
                "email": user_info["email"],
                "id": user_info["email"],
                "username": user_info["email"],
            }

OAUTH_PROVIDERS = [
    {
        "name": "my_company_name",
        "token_key": "access_token",
        "icon": "fa-circle-o",
        "remote_app": {
            "client_id": OKTA_CLIENT_ID,
            "client_secret": OKTA_CLIENT_SECRET,
            "client_kwargs": {"scope": "openid profile email groups"},
            "access_token_method": "POST",
            "api_base_url": f"{OKTA_BASE_URL}/oauth2/v1/",
            "access_token_url": f"{OKTA_BASE_URL}/oauth2/v1/token",
            "authorize_url": f"{OKTA_BASE_URL}/oauth2/v1/authorize",
            "server_metadata_url": f"{OKTA_BASE_URL}/.well-known/openid-configuration",
        },
    }
]

CUSTOM_SECURITY_MANAGER = CustomSsoSecurityManager

# a mapping from the values of `userinfo["role_keys"]` to a list of FAB roles
AUTH_ROLES_MAPPING = {
    "FAB_USERS": ["User"],
    "FAB_ADMINS": ["Admin"],
}

# if we should replace ALL the user's roles each login, or only on registration
AUTH_ROLES_SYNC_AT_LOGIN = True
```

I have reviewed all the relevant documentation and several other SO posts.